# Canvas.MouseLeftButtonDown event not raised after changing text in TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, textbox, mouseevent

I have noticed in my WPF application a strange behavior. If I edit or remove a text in any text box and try to click afterwards on a canvas, the first MouseLeftButtonDown event is often swallowed. If I try a second time, it works.

For demonstrating the problem, I have created a minimalist demo.

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Demo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Click Demo" Height="300" Width="400">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Margin="10,10,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Canvas Margin="10,38,10,10" MouseLeftButtonDown="Click" Background="Black"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C#:**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WPF_Demo
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Click!");
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Seems to be a problem of my Windows. I can reproduce it even with Explorer.

Comment: With the example you provided it works every time it's clicked.

Comment: Agree with @R.Rusev, the event is fired every time the Canvas is clicked. Which .NET version are you using?

Comment: I use .NET 4.6.1 (4.0.30319.42000) on Windows 10 and have still the problem :-(

Comment: Tends to be a mouse capture problem.  Odds that anybody can ever repro it from the snippet are zero.  Try another machine.